# Compare two Objects in a List and make it as one Object if any Duplicates

Tags: java

I have ArrayList of objects

```
public static void prepareList() {      
    
    Author a1 =new Author();
    Author a2 =new Author();
    Author a3 =new Author();
    Author a4 =new Author();
    Author a5 =new Author();
    Author a6 =new Author();
    Author a7 =new Author();        
    
    a1.setTransId("1111111");
    a1.setCountryCode("US");
    a1.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a1.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a2.setTransId("1111111");
    a2.setCountryCode("US");
    a2.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a2.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a3.setTransId("1111111");
    a3.setCountryCode("IN");
    a3.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a3.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a4.setTransId("222222");
    a4.setCountryCode("US");
    a4.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a4.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a5.setTransId("222222");
    a5.setCountryCode("US");
    a5.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a5.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a6.setTransId("3333333");
    a6.setCountryCode("US");
    a6.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a6.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    a7.setTransId("444444");
    a7.setCountryCode("US");
    a7.setCurrencyUSD(100000);
    a7.setExccessAmount(1000.00);
    
    
    Collection<Author> arrayListofObjects = new ArrayList<Author>();

    arrayListofObjects.add(a1);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a2);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a3);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a4);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a5);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a6);
    arrayListofObjects.add(a7);
    
    System.out.println("arrayListofObjects Size = " + arrayListofObjects.size());
    Map<String, List<Author>> mapList = arrayListofObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(authorObj -> authorObj.getTransId()+"_"+
            authorObj.getCountryCode()));
    System.out.println("Map Size = " + mapList.size());
    for(Entry<String, List<Author>> listobj : mapList.entrySet()) {
        String key = listobj.getKey();
        //System.out.println("key = " + key);
        List<Author> contraList = mapList.get(key);
        //System.out.println("contraList = " + contraList.size());
        //TODO if the list size is >1 then add CurrencyUSD and ExccessAmount, make as one object in that list (Size should be 1)
        if(contraList.size()>1) {
            System.out.println("key = " + key);
            System.out.println("contraList = " + contraList.size());
        }
    }
```

Here a1,a2 and a4,a5 are having same TransId, CountryCode
I want to make them one obj adding CurrencyUSD, ExccessAmount
achieving less time consuming way as I will be dealing with large data. Maybe using comparator, Streams.

I see one similar question but its time consuming not working as expected.

Comment: Use a set instead of a list?

Comment: So you have a list of objects that can contain duplicates which you want to remove or merge?

Comment: @Thomas merge by adding CurrencyUSD, ExccessAmount

Comment: In that case try to create a set, implement `equals()` and hashcode()` appropriately (in `Author`) and run over the list: try to add the element as a copy (so you don't change the original ones - if you're ok with that you don't need a copy) and  if the element already exists add the values as needed instead of adding it. Just make sure the values that can change are not part of `equals()` and `hashcode()` - if you need them to be part of this, use a map and add a separate key class.

Comment: @Thomas How can I do that

Comment: How can you do what? Add `equals()` and `hashcode()`? Create a copy? Iterate and merge?

Answer (score 1):

You were in the right track by grouping, just add a reducing collector:

```
Map<String, Author> mapList =
        arrayListofObjects.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(authorObj -> authorObj.getTransId() + "_" + authorObj.getCountryCode(),
                                                         Collectors.reducing(new Author("", "", 0, 0),
                                                                             (x,y) -> {
                                                             y.setCurrencyUSD(y.currencyUSD + x.currencyUSD);
                                                             y.setExccessAmount(y.exccessAmount + x.exccessAmount);
                                                             return y;
                                                         })));

final Collection<Author> aggregated = new ArrayList<>(mapList.values());
```

Comment: I am having exception as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Examples.App.lambda$1(App.java:205)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$reducing$42(Collectors.java:877)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$53(Collectors.java:1136)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)

Comment: I am having Exception in above logic

Comment: Above logic is working if exccessAmout data type is Integer. 
It’s throwing exception when it’s datatype is double

Comment: @ReachLoki Then change in the reducing step `0` to `0.0` to make it double. That is `Collectors.reducing(new Author("", "", 0, 0.0) ....`

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be

```
List<Author> out = arrayListofObjects.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toMap(e->e.getTransId()+e.getCountryCode(), Function.identity(), (a, b) -> {                         
                                a.setCurrencyUSD(a.getCurrencyUSD()+b.getCurrencyUSD());
                                a.setExccessAmount(a.getExccessAmount()+b.getExccessAmount());
                            return a;
                        }), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
out.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, I'll also add a version not using streams:

```
//map of unquie authors based on transid and country code, keep order of authors as per the list
Map<String, Author> uniqueAuthors = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

//iterate over the incoming list of authors
for( Author author : arrayListofObjects ) {
  //get the author based on "<transid>_<country_code>"
  //if the author doesn't exist create a new copy using the incoming key and 0 values
  Author uniqueAuthor = uniqueAuthors .computeIfAbsent(author.getTransId() + "_" + author.getCountryCode(),
    key -> new Author(author.getTransId(), author.getCountryCode(), 0,0 );

  //add the currency into the unique author
  uniqueAuthor.setCurrencyUSD(uniqueAuthor.getCurrencyUSD() + author.getCurrencyUSD());
  //add the excess amount into the unique author
  uniqueAuthor.setExccessAmount(uniqueAuthor.getExccessAmount() + author.getExccessAmount());
}

//create a list of unique authors that keeps the original ordering
List<Author> listOfUniqueAuthors = new ArrayList<>(uniqueAuthors.values());
```

Quick description of this approach:

- `LinkedHashMap` keeps the order of insertion and thus would help to get authors in the order in which they appeared in the original list (based on first appearance)
- `computeIfAbsent()` executes the lambda if there is no value for the given key and adds it to the map, otherwise just returns the existing value
- the lambda is used to create a new author with the same trans id and country code so we don't change the original elements
- we add the values of the current author from the list into the unique author from the map - if this is a new copy we'll just add the values to 0